# How do I avoid typing "android" for every attribute?

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete, attributes

I am new to Android development and am also a designer doubling as a front-end guy.

How can I avoid having to type `android:` every time I add an attribute?

In other text editors ([TextMate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate)), I can trigger snippets by typing a known trigger and <kbd>tab</kbd> to auto-complete the word. Is there something similar for Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just begin typing the second part of the keyword (what follows after `android:` and by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, Eclipse will insert the desired keyword for you prefixed with `android:`.

Answer (score 5):

You can bring up the auto-complete dialog by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> at the start of a new line.

Furthermore, I wanted to add a note about why you need to type `android:` at all (and how you can change it to whatever you want).

If you look at the first element in your layout file, there will be a line like this:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

If you change the word `android` here, then that will be the prefix you need to type - so if you instead set

```
xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

then all you attributes need only be preceeded by `a:`, such as in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"
    a:layout_height="fill_parent"
    a:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        a:layout_width="fill_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for this info, these explanations are very useful for us visual types whom often cannot absorb information until we break something that needs fixing.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> first. Then start typing anything. Use arrow keys to go through the list and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select one.

:-)

Comment: Also, tremendously helpful!